USB boot error: device descriptor read/64, error -110
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04. The system worked pretty well since June. After the last update my bluetooth doesn't work and I have an error message during boot saying
device descriptor read/64, error -110

The boot stick on this message for a couple of minutes and then it goes trough. I don't have problems using usb devices after boot, but the booting takes ages. Below I report the point where the boot stays for a long time. I'm note sure if the two issues are connected, but together with this problem the blootooth stopped to work. It's like the system doesn't see my bluetooth hardware at all. It all happened after the last upgrade.


It sounds like you have a USB device that happens to be malfunctioning. Or, perhaps you have a bad cable. To diagnose this, I would open a terminal and run sudo dmesg -W. (Note the "W" is capital.) As this command runs, it will display similar messages to that screen shot. From there, I'd disconnect and reconnect devices, to see which one gives the same errors. Replace the bad devices and/or cables.

I tried your command but it doesn't show any output. By the way, the messages shown above in my initial post have been pictured during boot with all usb cables and dongles detached.

In not sure I understand. Do you mean to tell me that sudo dmesg -W doesn't show anything, even when you are plugging/unplugging devices? Yhe idea is to leave it running and wait for the system to give it messages to display. Once you plug or unplug a device, that'll give it something to say.
